# Creating a custom pop up for Umbraco back office

Tags: c#, popup, umbraco

[Final EDIT] Here is [a link to the code I wrote](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ab982wca53wqcc/AhQRsxcWYK) in case it helps anyone.

> I think I have a solution. Umbraco uses asp.net files for their popups
>   which is something I haven't used yet but I think I can get the hang
>   of it. I don't know how to access the aspx from within my class,
>   should I make a code behind partial class?
>
> Thanks for any help.

I am developing a multi-lingual site, using Umbraco, where content nodes are automatically copied to each language as they are created. Is there any way to implement a custom popup to confirm that it should be copied to all instead?

This wouldn't actually be on the site, rather in the back office.

Or is it possible to open a browser popup with c# as all I really need is a bool value from a message box?

[EDIT: added possible solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this by adapting Umbraco's own create function. I made a new .aspx file and added the functionality that I needed to the code behind.

I was able to add [a context menu item](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/developing-with-umbraco/events/add-items-to-the-context-menu/TVPlayer) that allowed me to call my new page and from there called a method to duplicate the content.

From the method, I pass the new node and get the parent id. Then I compare all the node names for those that match and use the umbraco `document.copy()` method to recreate the content under each language at the correct position.

If I can make the code more generic then I will upload it as a package to Umbraco.